# Retrieve and save all Apple Push Notification Device Tokens in our server for APNS?

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications, provider

Am trying to integrate Apple Push Notification in my app. I have studied the Apple Document and other tutorials for my understanding. But, still i have a doubt to create a server and store all Apple Push Notification devicetokens in the database. Am not going to work on Server side but, i need to explain the approach to my client. I need to understand t`o create a APNS server provider and save all the apple push notification device tokens and retrieve all devicetoken and retrieve a single devicetoken to send notificaions`. Can you `please suggest me any sample code to save all apn devicetokens and retrieve from the server`? I suggest my client to create a `server in C#.net platform` is this correct? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, you just need to decide on a way for your app to let your servers know the device tokens. So, there are many ways to achieve this.

If your server side already involves a website, the easiest way would be to use HTTPS to do a POST request from your app. Then, the server-side code can be written as if it is handling form request from browsers. I can't really give you sample code since I don't know any C#, but this should be familiar to any web developer.